# How to Java web start application that gets download only once

Tags: java, jnlp, java-web-start

In my application, JNLP launches java webstart application which offers several functionalities like: open calculator, create File etc.

But, Jnlp should get downloaded only once. next time when user tries to invoke any functionality offered by Java web start, it should not give call to remote server but to localhost itself. 
How to make jnlp downloads once and listen to the requests?
Please help me on this.
It is something regarding httplistener? how to implement it?

Comment: couldnt understand what you mean by once downloaded it should not call remote server but localhost itself ? can you elaborate a bit more

Comment: Sure user395072, Actually jnlp downloads application.jar which carries many utility functions say, open calculator, open document etc.
but, jnlp should get downloaded once only, next time when user calls any function it should be local call and not remote web-server call.

Comment: To cache Jars and JNLP is the default behavior of JWS/JNLP.  This is not a real question.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to include the `offline-allowed` element in your JNLP file.

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/javaws/developersguide/syntax.html for more information.

Comment: Thanks parsifal, but m not sure how offline-allowed works, i mean  my jnlp will download application.jar from webserver first time and then whenver user tries to access any utility from application.jar it won't call web-server but it will give call as: localhost:port/filename.
even if i use offline allowed, how application.jar will be invoked next time? :(

Comment: @user2136845 - Java Web Start caches the JARs that it downloads. If all you're looking to do is run the application again, it can run that application from the cache. I have no idea what you mean by "give call as: localhost:port/filename"; if your application needs to contact a webserver, then of course it won't find your webserver running on the user's machine.

Comment: yes I want to run cached application parsifal, but don't know how to do it, how to call cached application. please help

Comment: @user2136845 - the best I can do is point you at the documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/javaws/developersguide/faq.html#104

Comment: gr8, parsifal Thanku,  hw to accept your ans on stackoverflow.. sorry bt m new here

Answer (score 0):

To see the files (JWS) you have already downloaded follow :
Control panel > Java >General>View...your all downloaded files should be present here.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt you can prevent (by merely JWS/JNLP means) running an JWS application again. You can however try, after you run your application to create listening socket. If succeeded, then you wait on this port (in separate thread) and wait for incoming messages --- a "magic number" of your choice. If you get one, you reply with some code telling the client, that "this application is already running". However if you aren't able to create listening socket, then you try to send to it a magic number and listen for the reply. If the reply is as mentioned above, you know that your application is running and you should quit this instance. If you get some unexpected reply, then you repeat above steps starting with the creation of listening socket, but on the port with higher number --- and as to the client, if you get unexpected answer, you try to send magic number to the port +1 socket.

Comment: Thanks Cromax, will try this approach, I was trying to run cached application.